# Use the definition of convergence of a sequence to show the sequence $a_n=4(\frac{3}7)^n +9$ converges.

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I know the definition of convergence, I know how to start off proving a sequence converges. On this sequence,

$a_n = 4  (\dfrac{3}7)^n +9$, $n \in \mathbb N$.

I don't understand how to show epsilon is less then the mod of the sequence takeaway the limit of the sequence.

Comment: What do you think is the limit of this particular sequence?

Answer (score 3):

With [Bernoulli's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli%27s_inequality)
$$a_n-9=4\left(\frac37\right)^n=\dfrac{4}{(\frac73)^n}=\dfrac{4}{(1+\frac43)^n}\leq\dfrac{4}{1+\frac{4n}{3}}<\dfrac{3}{n}$$

Comment: @msm thanks for your edit,